# Many rpsec tests with test_sign_in fail after upgrading to Rails 3.1, maybe a cookie problem?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I have upgraded to Rails 3.1 and everything seems to work fine. But the tests (RSpec) fail anyhow, e.g. the following one:

```
describe "for admin user" do

  before(:each) do
    @city = Factory(:city)
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @business = Factory(:business, :user_id => @user.id, 
                        :city_id => @city.id)
    @admin = test_sign_in(Factory(:user, :email => "admin@example.it", 
                                  :admin => true))
  end

  it "should have an edit link for all businesses in show city" do
    get :show, :id => @city
    response.should have_selector('a',
      :href => "/businesses/#{@business.id}-Factory-business-city-Factory-business/edit")
  end
end
```

This worked fine with Rails 3.0.8, but now the test fails. Test log says:

[1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `users` (`admin`, `created_at`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `name`, `salt`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2011-09-21 10:30:30', 'admin@example.it', '68f8a34e0243a642662fe2b6ea8ed7c714d042750a66ce542f2df288caefac32', 'Admin Name', '6df34c304d79437d495e60d2d34e1028489731afa96690efbc25c714224edb1f', '2011-09-21 10:30:30')

Processing by CitiesController#show as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1

[1m[36mCity Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 942 LIMIT 1[0m

[1m[35mCity Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 942 LIMIT 1

[1m[36mCity Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 942 LIMIT 1[0m

[1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m

So, it seems there is no user id (NULL), but the admin was created correctly before. Might this be a cookie problem?

The test group in my Gemfile is:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.6.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
end
```

My test.rb is

```
Project::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite.  You never need to work with it otherwise.  Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs.  Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the test database.
  # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
  # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
  # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Allow pass debug_assets=true as a query parameter to load pages with unpackaged assets
  config.assets.allow_debugging = true
end
```

And this is my spec_helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However, 
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  unless defined?(Rails)
    require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"
  end
  require 'rspec/rails'

  # Requires supporting files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in ./support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}

  Rspec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, comment the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    ### Part of a Spork hack. See http://bit.ly/arY19y
    # Emulate initializer set_clear_dependencies_hook in 
    # railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear

    def test_sign_in(user)
      controller.sign_in(user)
    end
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
end
```

Thank you for your suggestions/answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by following this question:

[Cookies do not persist in Rspec on rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821692/cookies-do-not-persist-in-rspec-on-rails-3-1)

Not a perfect way, but it'll work!