# Why are my RSpec tests failing, but my app is working?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, railstutorial.org

I just finished [chapter 10 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top), adding the ability to edit/update, index, and destroy users. Everything appears to be working properly in my app, but many of my tests are failing when I run RSpec.

I have the users_controller_spec set up exactly as the book does it and my application code is the same as well. Could one issue may be that I am using Rails 3.1.1 as opposed to Rails 3.0 which he uses in the book? It hasn't really been an issue for previous tests, just occasionally for a few different lines of code. The issues started appearing after I started [section 10.2.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3arequiring_signed_in_users).

Here is the list of errors that I am seeing and please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

```
1) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should be successful
 Failure/Error: response.should be_success
   expected success? to return true, got false
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "All users")
   expected following output to contain a <title>All users</title> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should have an element for each user
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
   expected following output to contain a <li>Richard Berger</li> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:42:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:41:in `each'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should paginate users
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
   expected following output to contain a <div.pagination/> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:48:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) UsersController GET 'edit' should be successful
 Failure/Error: response.should be_success
   expected success? to return true, got false
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:184:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) UsersController GET 'edit' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
   expected following output to contain a <title>Edit user</title> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:189:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) UsersController GET 'edit' should have a link to change the Gravatar
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("a", :href => gravatar_url, :content => "change")
   expected following output to contain a <a href='http://gravatar.com/emails'>change</a> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:195:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) UsersController PUT 'update' failure should render the 'edit' page
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template('edit')
   expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <"">
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:214:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) UsersController PUT 'update' failure should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
   expected following output to contain a <title>Edit user</title> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:219:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

10) UsersController PUT 'update' success should change the user's attributes
 Failure/Error: @user.name.should  == @attr[:name]
   expected: "New Name"
        got: "Richard Berger" (using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:232:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

11) UsersController PUT 'update' success should redirect to the user show page
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users/1> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/signin>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:238:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

12) UsersController PUT 'update' success should have a flash message
 Failure/Error: flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
   expected: /updated/
        got: nil (using =~)
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:243:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

13) UsersController authentication of edit/update pages for signed-in users should require matching users for 'edit'
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(root_path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/signin>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:276:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

14) UsersController authentication of edit/update pages for signed-in users should require matching users for 'update'
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(root_path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/signin>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:281:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

15) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' as a non-admin user should protect the page
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(root_path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/signin>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:303:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

16) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' as an admin user should destroy the user
 Failure/Error: lambda do
   count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:315:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

17) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' as an admin user should redirect to the users page
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(users_path)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/signin>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:322:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**UPDATE:**

I solved 2 of the errors, but most are still persisting. One issue appears to be that when the test is trying to "get :index", it's not finding the correct page because of a redirect (to the /signin page). I did not institute any redirects (on purpose anyway), but maybe someone has an idea of how this might have happened and how it could be fixed?

**UPDATE #2:**

Per @bkempner's request, here's the relevant code from the users_controller_spec and the users_controller (users_controller_spec first). Lot of code, but lot of errors...:

```
describe "for signed-in users" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
    second = Factory(:user, :email => "another@example.com")
    third  = Factory(:user, :email => "another@example.net")

    @users = [@user, second, third]
    30.times do
      @users << Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))
    end
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get :index
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should have the right title" do
    get :index
    response.should have_selector("title", :content => "All users")
  end

  it "should have an element for each user" do
    get :index
    @users[0..2].each do |user|
      response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
    end
  end

  it "should paginate users" do
    get :index
    response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
    response.should have_selector("span.diabled", :content => "Previous")
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2", :content => "2")
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2", :content => "Next")
  end
end

describe "GET 'edit'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    test_sign_in(@user)
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should have the right title" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
  end

  it "should have a link to change the Gravatar" do
    get :edit, :id => @user
    gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/emails"
    response.should have_selector("a", :href => gravatar_url, :content => "change")
  end
end

describe "PUT 'update'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    test_sign_in(@user)
  end

  describe "failure" do

    before(:each) do
      @attr = { :email => "", :name => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "" }
    end

    it "should render the 'edit' page" do
      put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
      response.should render_template('edit')
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
    end
  end

  describe "success" do

    before(:each) do
      @attr = { :name => "New Name", :email => "user@example.org", :password => "barbaz", :password_confirmation => "barbaz" }
    end

    it "should change the user's attributes" do
      put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
      @user.reload
      @user.name.should  == @attr[:name]
      @user.email.should == @attr[:email]
    end

    it "should redirect to the user show page" do
      put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
      response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
    end

    it "should have a flash message" do
      put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
      flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
    end
  end
end

describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do

  describe "for signed-in users" do

    before(:each) do
      wrong_user = Factory(:user, :email => "user@example.net")
      test_sign_in(wrong_user)
    end

    it "should require matching users for 'edit'" do
      get :edit, :id => @user
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
    end

    it "should require matching users for 'update'" do
      get :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
end

describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  describe "as a non-admin user" do
    it "should protect the page" do
      test_sign_in(@user)
      delete :destroy, :id => @user
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end

  describe "as an admin user" do

    before(:each) do
      admin = Factory(:user, :email => "admin@example.com", :admin => true)
      test_sign_in(admin)
    end

    it "should destroy the user" do
      lambda do
        delete :destroy, :id => @user
      end.should change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "should redirect to the users page" do
      delete :destroy, :id => @user
      response.should redirect_to(users_path)
    end
  end
end
```

And now the entire users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

def index
  @title = "All users"
  @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = @user.name
end

def new
  @user = User.new
  @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @title = "Edit user"
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Edit user"
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  redirect_to users_path
end

private

  def authenticate
    deny_access unless signed_in?
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Comment: did you figure this out? you lat edited 20 days ago and i just started porting to 3.1 and having same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821692/cookies-do-not-persist-in-rspec-on-rails-3-1).

basically RSPEC needs both @current_user and current user to be set for sign_in and sign_out.  Weird and annoying, but perhaps the reason one might consider using Devise in a production app!

Comment: so this seems to have solved my issue, although i'm still not totally sure why. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Providing your controller and test code would be helpful.  But without them my guess would be that you are missing this in the before block for your failing tests:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
test_sign_in(@user)
```

The redirection is happening because of whatever authorization logic is being used in the tutorial, i think it is detailed in 10.11 and 10.12.

This is a common gotcha i see in controller tests with auth, hopefully that's all that it is for you as well.

EDIT:

Thanks for providing your code.

Here's a few things i noticed:

1.) Failures 1-14, 19 are due to the user authentication not working, specifically signed_in?. Are your session controller tests passing?  You should definitely make sure those pass before testing the users controller since it depends on that functionality.

2.) Failures 15-18 are because you probably didn't create the migration to add the boolean attribute in Listing 10.35 -or- you need to run the migration on your test database: `rake db:test:prepare`

Sorry i couldn't pin point all your problems but hopefully gives you a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I don't think that's the issue. Gonna add my controller and test code to the main post now though to double check.

Comment: hmm, thanks for sticking with the issue. all my session controller tests ARE passing, so don't think that's the issue. also pretty sure i migrated the attribute and the database. just updated the list of errors also because there were a couple minor changes. still don't know what's wrong unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Check that `deny_access` in `SessionsHelper` is defined before the `private` block.

The book has a typo that implies that you should put `deny_access` at the end of the module. Unfortunately this means that the function is defined as private.

```
module SessionsHelper
  .
  .
  .
  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
  end
end
```

The corrected code on the [Railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3adeny_access) website is below:

```
module SessionsHelper
  .
  .
  .
  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
  end

  private
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i've already got the deny_access in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and using Rails 3.1.3.  This is my solution.

First, make sure both:

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end
```

are in sessions_helper.rb

Also, in sessions_helper.rb change:

```
def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    current_user.nil
end
```

to

```
def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user.nil
end
```

One more thing.

In spec_helper.rb change:

```
def test_sign_in(user)
    controller.sign_in(user)
end
```

to

```
def test_sign_in(user)
    controller.current_user = user
end
```

See if that helps, I haven't completed the chapter, but this gets me through 10.2.1.  Someone with more experience can comment on **why** this works.  I read another solution that wrote around depending on before_filter to get rspec to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `render_views` call after top level `describe` in the users_controller_spec?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today using rails 3.1.3. However, I went to the github site for the railstutorial sample app and noticed the sessions_helper.erb there had some changes.

1.) Add the 'self' key word to 'current_user' in the sign_in(user) method:

```
def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  self.current_user = user
end
```

2.) This also goes for the 'sign_out' method, add the 'self' keyword to 'current_user'

```
def sign_out
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  self.current_user = nil
end
```

I made no other changes and all tests pass.

Comment: interesting, so i'm not sure why, but adding self DID NOT work, while adding a second line referring to @current_user (as [referenced here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821692/cookies-do-not-persist-in-rspec-on-rails-3-1)) did work...