# Integration test rails not working login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, authentication

I have such tests:

```
class LockableFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

      context 'A user' do

        setup do
          @organization = Factory(:organization)
          @user = Factory(:user, :organization => @organization)
        end

        should "login after 4 attempts" do
          4.times do
            post_via_redirect '/users/sign_in', 'user[username]' => @user.username, 'user[password]' => "bad_password"
            assert_equal '/users/sign_in', path
            assert_equal 'Invalid email or password.', flash[:alert]
          end
          post_via_redirect '/users/sign_in', 'user[username]' => @user.username, 'user[password]' => "password"
          assert_equal "/registrations/#{@user.id}/edit", path
          assert_nil flash[:alert]
        end
```

It doesn't work but the application is okay. I would like to test attempts to login into the application. After 4 attempts it should be possible to login.

The code controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_filter :log_failed_login, :only => :new

  private
  def log_failed_login
    if request.filtered_parameters["user"]
      user = User.find_by_username(request.filtered_parameters["user"]["username"])
      if user
        if user.first_failed_attempt.nil?
          user.first_failed_attempt = Time.now
        else
          if user.first_failed_attempt + 15.minutes <= Time.now
            user.failed_attempts = 1
            user.first_failed_attempt = Time.now
          end
        end
        user.save
      end

    end
  end


def failed_login?
  (options = env["warden.options"]) && options[:action] == "unauthenticated"
end

end
```

Comment: Please post why it doesn't work: errors, crashes, exceptions... And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What's the counting mechanism to let the application know that it already executed four tries?

Cookies? [Cookies do not persist in Rspec on rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821692/cookies-do-not-persist-in-rspec-on-rails-3-1)