# Rails Tutorial add test for user signing out but fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm going through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. I downloaded the source code [samle_app_rails_4](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4).
Then I add a test for signing out a user, it works fine in my browser, but in Rspec,
it fails. I changed nothing to the source code but add this to the `user_pages_spec.rb`.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "User pages" do

  describe "sign out" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before :each do
      sign_in user
    end

    it "should sign out a user" do
      delete signout_path
      expect(page).to have_content("Sign in")
    end
  end
end
```

The `sign_in` method is defined in `spec/support/utilities.rb`

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

The `sessions_controller.rb` is like this( I ignored create action here.)

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

And `sessions_helper.rb`is like this:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token  = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

I have tried many solutions, post an issue on github, and this [Cookies do not persist in Rspec on rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821692/cookies-do-not-persist-in-rspec-on-rails-3-1)

I also go through these questions  but nothing is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/railstutorial.org.

I even upgrade my rspec and capybara gem. Maybe something wrong with my test file?
`delete signout_path` is not right for signing out a user?
I find it's weird in sample app, as an user has logged in, he can still visit signin_path and signup_path.

Wish someone can help me, big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page` variable you are accessing in your example is only available with use of Capybara methods such as `visit` and `click`. By directly issuing the HTTP `delete` operation, you are bypassing Capybara and the setting of the `page` variable.

You can access the response body as `response.body` using your example, but note that the tutorial shows a test of sign-out at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-signout_test using a different request spec and Capybara's `click` method.

Comment: This worked for me. But I also found that it use `before { put user_path(user) }` in authentication_pages_spec.rb, this is accessed by something like curl, right? So if I want to sign out a user normally, I should use click sign out link, got it. Big thanks!

Comment: I didn't find any use of `put`, but I did find use of `post` and `patch`. It looks like Michael has incorporated controller examples within this request spec. I'm not sure why that is. Perhaps he wanted to keep the authentication and authorizations examples close to each other.  As for use of `curl`, I'm not sure what you mean by that. In the examples I saw, he was just checking the value of `response`.

Comment: Sorry, `put` is for Rails 3.2, I mean `patch user_path(user)`.Yeah, he  wanted to check that non-signed-in users can not update a user, thank s for your nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the code, `SessionsController#destroy` redirects to `static_pages#home` which does not contain the string "Sign in"

Comment: The sign-in link is in the header, at `app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

in your spec you redirect to root_url after signout the user, so you should have the string "Sign in" in the root_url, just add for example `<h1>Sign in</h1>` to your root_url view and it will be passing, if your root url don't contains the form to sign in, in this case you should redirect to signin_path (wich will be contains the string "Sign in")

Comment: As Peter says, sign-in link is in the header: `app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb`.